# Facebook Logout Button for My Website (Not Facebook Connect Logout)

Tags: facebook, button, redirect, logout

I was wondering if it is possible to create a "logout" button for my site that will log a user out of facebook and then redirect them to a specific URL ? Let me elaborate, I work in a retail store and I have a mounted iPad so customers can "like" our facebook page (by using a traditional facebook like button). Currently, when customer's select "like" it opens a new window where facebook asks for a username and password, and then immediately after the customer hits "Submit" it re-directs them back to a specific URL where I say "thanks for liking us"...the only problem is that it keeps them logged into facebook.

I'm hoping to put a logout button on my "thank you for liking us" URL so they can click that to logout (without going back to facebook) and then it re-directs back to the page with the like button for the next customer.

I have tried facebook connect but it's so many steps because users have to allow the app etc. that I'm hoping to avoid that. Maybe a way that clears the facebook cookies or anything else? I'm so out of ideas that anything will help!

Answer (score 0):

Include the Facebook JS SDK and then call `FB.logout()` either on click of the link, or on the thank you page.

Answer (score 0):

Tested, not working even with FB.logout(), because once you logged in facebook.com, then fb cookie will be injected automatically, there's no way to remove it unless you've logout from facebook.com.:/